# Vue Array in Array

Tags: vue.js

I have an array

[image: Array]

```
var content = new Vue({
    el: '#content',
    data: {
        items: data
    }
});

<div class="short" v-for="item in items">
    <div class="top">
        <img :src="item.userAvatar" />
        {{ item.userName }}
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
        There must be an array of items
    </div>
</div>
```

All values from the array are output, but how do you get the values out of the array of items that is inside the data? The items do not depend on me, the rows are permanently deleted and added.

Comment: how is the structure of the `items`?

Comment: updated the image of the array

Comment: I don't get the question. Can you update / improve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try using for loop to iterate the items such as:

```
var content = new Vue({
    el: '#content',
    data: {
        items: data
    }
});

<div class="short" v-for="item in items">
    <div class="top">
        <img :src="item.userAvatar" />
        {{ item.userName }}
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
        <div v-for="(i, idx) in item.items" :key="idx">{{ i.name }} {{ i.type }}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your image shows the `userAvatar` and `userName` are members of the Array object, and not members of each item in the Array. That is, there is one `userName` for the entire Array. You would refer to it as `items.userName`.